# How to handle custom default values of plugin with FOSCKEditorBundle?

Tags: symfony, ckeditor, overriding

I would like to override the default values of the "table" plugin, for example the cellspadding (txtCellSpace).

Using:

- Symfony: 6.4
- friendsofsymfony/ckeditor-bundle: v2.4 (CKeditor v4 in it)

Without the FOSCKEditorBundle, we should add some code like this in the config.js file:

```
CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function( ev ) {
  var dialogName = ev.data.name;
  var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;
  if(dialogName === 'table') {
    var infoTab = dialogDefinition.getContents('info');
    var cellSpacing = infoTab.get('txtCellSpace');
    cellSpacing['default'] = "0";
  }
});
```

The problem is: I don't have a config.js file to make this code working, as I'm using the FOSCKEditorBundle.

I've tried to override the ckeditor_form.html.twig to append some custom JS like documented here: https://symfony.com/bundles/FOSCKEditorBundle/current/usage/append-javascript.html by creating a new ckeditor_form.html.twig into the Symfony's templates folder that extends the original one, and calling it into the backend/config/packages/twig.yaml with:

```
  default_path: "%kernel.project_dir%/templates"
    form_themes:
      - "ckeditor_widget.html.twig"
```

But my file was never called.

Has anyone already tried to do something like this?

Answer (score 0):

The right way to override table plugin's default value was to include custom Javascript.

After many tries, I've managed to do it, thanks to https://symfony.com/doc/6.4/bundles/override.html.

**twig.yaml**:

```
twig:
  default_path: "%kernel.project_dir%/templates"
  form_themes:
    - "bundles/FOSCKEditorBundle/Form/ckeditor_widget.html.twig"
```

**/templates/bundles/FOSCKEditorBundle/Form/ckeditor_widget.html.twig**:

```
{% extends '@!FOSCKEditor/Form/ckeditor_widget.html.twig' %}

{% block ckeditor_widget_extra %}
  CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function( ev ) {
    var dialogName = ev.data.name;
    var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;
    if(dialogName === 'table') {
      var infoTab = dialogDefinition.getContents('info');
      var cellSpacing = infoTab.get('txtCellSpace');
      cellSpacing['default'] = "0";
    }
  });
{% endblock %}
```